# Add single bar to a stacked bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In order to show the difference between three measurements against a single one, I need to combine a regular bar plot and with a stacked one. However, once I use a stacked bar plot, the single datum is shifted:

[image: Imgur]

This is what produced the plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    xmin=0,
  ]

  \addplot coordinates {
    ({0.394240+1.067584}, 0)
    ({0.614592+1.247520}, 1)
    ({1.862848+1.615360}, 2)
    ({4.025184+2.461248}, 3)
  };

  \addplot coordinates {
    ({0.333824+0.553664}, 0)
    ({0.602816+1.236160}, 1)
    ({1.719200+0.600512}, 2)
    ({3.526432+1.282208}, 3)
  };

  \addplot coordinates {
    ({0.334912+0.522688}, 0)
    ({0.642980+0.701760}, 1)
    ({1.873760+0.997440}, 2)
    ({3.856416+1.302432}, 3)
  };

  \addplot coordinates {
    (0.630336, 0.5)
    (1.925728, 1.5)
    (6.348640, 2.5)
    (15.193056, 3.5)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is it possible to shift the orange bar back to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution. Since a single bar is an `xbar` without being stacked. So this solution proposes the `axis` environment to be used twice, one for `xbar stacked` and one for `xbar`. The final result has a group of floating black bars, which are for demonstration purpose. Simply remove the `addplot` command indicated by arrow <--- can get rid of them.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    xmin=0,xmax=40, ymax=4
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {
    ({0.394240+1.067584}, 0)
    ({0.614592+1.247520}, 1)
    ({1.862848+1.615360}, 2)
    ({4.025184+2.461248}, 3)
  };

  \addplot coordinates {
    ({0.333824+0.553664}, 0)
    ({0.602816+1.236160}, 1)
    ({1.719200+0.600512}, 2)
    ({3.526432+1.282208}, 3)
  };

  \addplot coordinates {
    ({0.334912+0.522688}, 0)
    ({0.642980+0.701760}, 1)
    ({1.873760+0.997440}, 2)
    ({3.856416+1.302432}, 3)
  };
%   Remove  this plot will remove the black bar
  \addplot coordinates { %<---
    (0.630336, 0.5)      %
    (1.925728, 1.5)      %
    (6.348640, 2.5)      %
    (15.193056, 3.5) };  %<---
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar, 
    axis y line=none,
    xmin=0,xmax=40, ymax=4,
]
  \addplot[fill=orange]  coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (0.630336, 0.5) 
    (1.925728, 1.5)
    (6.348640, 2.5)
    (15.193056, 3.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly (apart from fiddling with the ylabels)!