# Plot a stacked bar plot with specialised x axis range

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

How can I make a bar chart with custom x axis range which is from 100 to 0 then to 100?

The figure should look like this:

[image]

(Figure is in https://doi.org/10.1145/2971648.2971676)

Also, how to make the neutral bar align its middle with 0?

This answer is somehow close, but cannot do the above: 
[Add single bar to a stacked bar plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182613/add-single-bar-to-a-stacked-bar-plot)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I have tried to modify the one in my link "Add single bar to a stacked bar plot". That's the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I present a solution that should be very near your requirements. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    % load PGFPlots ColorBrewer library for adequate colors/an adequate `cycle list'
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.colorbrewer,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use the advanced positioning of
        % the axis labels
        compat=1.3,
        % add the small font size also to the legend entries
        small/.append style={
            legend style={
                font={\small},
            },
        },
        % define a custom style which is used for both `axis' environments
        my axis style/.style={
            % use the (appended) `small' style
            small,
            % set axis with and height
            width=\axisdefaultwidth,
            height=21mm,
            % set axis x limits
            xmin=-100,
            xmax=100,
            % use stacked xbars ...
            xbar stacked,
            % ... where the negative values are plotted separately
            stack negative=separate,    % <-- default
            % align xticks outside ...
            xtick align=outside,
            % ... and only on the lower axis line
            xtick pos=lower,
            % don't show yticks
            ytick=\empty,
            % at x = 0 stuff should be handled differently
            extra x ticks={0},
            extra x tick style={
                xmajorgrids,
                grid style={
                    black,
                    dashed,
                },
                xticklabel=\empty,
            },
            % rotate the ylabel (back)
            ylabel style={
                rotate=-90,
            },
            % draw the gridlines on top of the bars
            axis on top,
            % define the style of the legend
            legend style={
                at={(0.5,1)},
                anchor=south,
                yshift=2pt,
                legend columns=3,
            },
            legend cell align=left,
            % this loads a proper colormap which contains the colors we want to use
            colormap/RdBu-5,
            % Now we create the cycle list on our own.
            % Because bars are drawn from 0 on, we need to change the order of
            % colors of the above loaded `cycle list'; first the 3 negative bars
            % and then the 3 positive bars
            cycle list={
                {index of colormap={2},fill=.,draw=.},
                {index of colormap={1},fill=.,draw=.},
                {index of colormap={0},fill=.,draw=.},
                {index of colormap={2},fill=.,draw=.},
                {index of colormap={3},fill=.,draw=.},
                {index of colormap={4},fill=.,draw=.},
            },
            % since we have only one bar per `axis' environment and no y value
            % we can state an arbitrary value here
            table/y expr=0,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        % state the values for the different categories
        %   index 0: strongly disagree
        %   index 1: disagree
        %   index 2: (negative) neutral
        %   index 3: (positive) neutral
        %   index 4: agree
        %   index 5: strongly agree
        \pgfplotstableread{
            0 0 -5 3 56 37
        }\TableOne
        \pgfplotstableread{
            0 -10 -10 8 45 30
        }\TableTwo
    \begin{axis}[
        % load the created style
        my axis style,
        % misuse the `ylabel'
        ylabel={(a)},
        % don't show `xticklabels' on the upper plot
        xticklabels={},
        % list the legend entries
        legend entries={
            strongly disagree,
            disagree,
            neutral,,               % <-- show neutral only once
            agree,
            strongly agree%
        },
        % give the upper `axis' a (node) name
        name=upper,
    ]
        % to get the right order of legend entries with the right corresponding
        % colors, we need to provide proper `\addlegendimage' commands
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,1,2,0,3,4} {
            \addlegendimage{index of colormap={#1},fill=.,draw=.}
        }

        % now we add the bars in a proper order
        \foreach \i in {2,1,0,3,4,5} {
            \addplot table [x index=\i] {\TableOne};
        }
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        % position the "lower" `axis' environment properly, relative to the
        % "upper" `axis' environment ...
        at={(upper.below south)},
        % ... and state a proper `anchor' for the "lower" `axis' environment
        anchor=north,
        % only show positive values as `xticklabels'
        xticklabel={
            \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\tick < 0, -\tick, \tick)}
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
        },
        xlabel={Percent},
        xlabel style={
            yshift=2ex,
        },
        ylabel={(b)},
    ]
        \foreach \i in {2,1,0,3,4,5} {
            \addplot table [x index=\i] {\TableTwo};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Very good answer. I upvote you.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! Any idea to remove the minus sign on the left side of x axis?